# ec2 is not accessible by http using domain in several countries but accessible using public domain

Tags: http, amazon-ec2

My ec2 instance is accessible using public dns from any where of the world on the other hand its not accessible in different counties using the domain name.

Any idea where to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean different "countries"? Therefore do you mean your public DNS works from some countries and not others? My guess is that either your DNS name or possibly even the public IP is being blocked in those countries.